# Broadcast Notifications to public channel using Laravel 5.4 and pusher

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher

My notification RealtimeNotification.php has:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['broadcast'];
}

public function toBroadcast($notifiable){
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'name' => 'John Snow'
    ]);
}
```

In my view, i have a pusher object that is connected with my pusher account:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-App.User.1');
channel.bind('App\\Notifications\\RealtimeNotification', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

So if i am using like this, Pusher gives me this error in console, maybe because it's a private channel i didn't configure any auth for Pusher

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
```

My question is, how can i broadcast to a public channel ?

In Laravel 5.4 documentations, says :
"Notifications will broadcast on a private channel formatted using a {notifiable}.{id} convention."

I think there shoud be a method for this, but i still can't find it, and any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: nope. maybe it's still not implemented

Comment: I actually managed to get this working using laravel echo

Comment: share it with us if you want. i think will be helpfull

Comment: No problem give me a couple of hours as just leaving work, I stripped laravel echo down to be a stand-alone script and works great, Will share with you this evening and you should be able to make use of it :)

Comment: anytime u want. thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The channels should be instances of Channel, PrivateChannel, or  PresenceChannel. Instances of Channel represent public channels that any user may subscribe to, while PrivateChannels and PresenceChannels represent private channels that require channel authorization......As explained from the laravel official doc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will works on 5.4, I'm using `broadcastOn` function in my laravel 5.6 app, put it on your notification class..

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [
        new \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel('this-public-channel')
    ];
}
```

In blade using laravel echo:

```
window.Echo.channel('this-public-channel').notification((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```